# Varnish 4.0 + Magento 1.9 | Login on the first time does not work

Tags: magento, varnish

So, I have setup Varnish 4.0 + Magento 1.9 using the nexaccess module for Varnish, and I am having some weird behavior on the store with HTTPS.
Since varnish does not support SSL, I am using pound as a SSL termination, and pound acts like a proxy to varnish.

The module is: https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine

Support to SSL: https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/wiki/SSL_Support

Now the issue in details is the following:

When the user visits the website he is over a HTTP connection in the homepage, when he clicks on the "login" button, he get's redirected to the login page which is over HTTPS. If we look at the cookies in this point, both frontend and frontend_cid are set. When the user try to login he get's redirected back to the login page with no error messages (if we look at the cookies again now, they got generated again, they are different from the first request). If the user try to login again, for the second time, everything works just fine.

Now some behaviors I was able to track:

- When I disable HTTPs everything works just fine
- If I remove all the cookies from my browser, go direct to the HTTPs login page, and try to login, it does the same thing, first time does not work, second time works great. However, if I go direct to the login page, and before the first try to login just refresh the page, the login works with no problem (and the cookies are not regenerated in this case)
- I believe it has something to do with a fix Magento made for preventing MITM attacks in the file app/code/core/Mage/core/Model/Session/Abtract/Varien.php (class Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien. In this file, starting at line 135 magento starts to make a few checks in order to prevent this type of attack. If I comment out this part of the code the problem does not happen with the login page.
- I tried to change Pound for Nginx, and Apache2 for proxying the request to varnish, however they all had the same issue, so I think the problem is not here.

Here is my configuration files:

pound.cfg

```
 TimeOut 3600

 ListenHTTPS
    Address server_ip
    Port    port
    Cert    "my cert path"
    xHTTP   2
    RewriteLocation 1
    Ciphers "RC4:!SSLv2:!ADH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!LOW:!EXP"
    AddHeader "Ssl-Offloaded: 1"
End

Service
    BackEnd
        Address varnish_ip
        Port    varnish_port
    End
End
```

Varnish VCL:

The nexaccess module generated this and sends to the server, you can check for the template here: github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/blob/devel/app/code/community/Nexcessnet/Turpentine/misc/version-4.vcl

Comment: Is there anyone at least with Varnish 4 + SSL termination working with no problems in order to compare the setups?